# Question about objects in set theory. Terence Tao Analysis 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading the chapter on set theory in Terence Tao's Analysis I.He gives an axiom on singleton sets which goes
"If a is an object, then there
exists a set {a} whose only element is a, i.e., for every object y, we have
y ∈ {a} if and only if y = a;"
My question is, how do we know that equality is defined for the objects in discussion.Is there an axiom ? The author gives a definition on when two sets are considered to be equal but he isn't clear about whether all objects are sets or not.

Comment: In this context, all objects are sets. And the axiom for equality of sets is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality : two sets are equal iff they have the same elements.

Comment: The author later defines functions to be not sets, but objects. @AnneBauval

Comment: See his remark 3.1.3 p.34 (3rd ed., 2016), ending with "*The two types of theories* [set theory with or without urelements] *are more or less equivalent for the purposes of doing mathematics, and so we shall take an agnostic position as to whether all objects are sets or not*". (See also Definition 3.1.4, which is the axiom of extensionality mentionned above.) Oh but I understand your question only now! (about equality of [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement)), and I feel unable to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I will just stay with the intuitive notion of a set and skip the axiomatic part.I guess that isn't really essential
for learning analysis.